# How to select multiple attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml schema on where I want to use linq to query 2 attributes. I have searched around but have not found the right solution.

```
<Object class="MA" Name="Sample">
  <bist name="act">false</bist>
  <bist name="Dynamic">1234</bist>
  <bist name="Fast">false</bist>
  <bist name="plane">false</bist>
  <bist name="Tnl">2232</bist>
</Object>
```

For the xml above, after getting the value of "Dynamic" and comparing it with oldTnl variable, if equal, I want to select or get "Tnl" value (2232).

Currently, I am testing with this code and successfully getting the value of "Dynamic" but I really want the value of "Tnl".

```
 private void mGetTnlFromXML(string oldTnl)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("sample.xml");

        var bt = from p in doc.Descendants()
                  where (string)p.Attribute("name") == "Dynamic"
                  select p;

        foreach (string b in bt)
        {
            if (b == oldTnl)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Something like:

```
private void mGetTnlFromXML(string oldTnl)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("sample.xml");

        var bt = from p in doc.Descendants()
                  where (string)p.Attribute("name") == "Dynamic"
                  //is there are way i can also find "Tnl" here and use 
                  //later?
                  select p; //or select "Tnl" here.

        foreach (string b in bt)
        {
            if (b == oldTnl)
            {
                //select "Tnl" value (2232)
                //use "Tnl" value (2232)
                //do something....
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance... I am still learning LinQ :).

---

Updated XML:

```
<Root>
  <Data>
    <Object class="MA" Name="Sample">
      <bist name="act">false</bist>
      <bist name="Dynamic">1234</bist>
      <bist name="Fast">false</bist>
      <bist name="plane">false</bist>
      <bist name="Tnl">2232</bist>
    </Object>
  </Data>
</Root>
```

Comment: So you want the value of the `bist` element where the `name` attribute is **"Tnl"** and there exists a sibling `bist` element that has a `name` attribute with a value of **"dynamic"**?

Comment: i need the dynamic for comparison then I will get the Tnl after that. If the dynamic is not equal or does not exist, it does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you want this:

```
private void mGetTnlFromXML(string oldTnl)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("sample.xml");
    var dynamic = doc.Root.Elements("bist").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "dynamic").First().Value;
    if (dynamic == oldTnl)
    {
        var tnl = doc.Root.Elements("bist").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Tnl").First().Value;
        MessageBox.Show(tnl);
    };
}
```

That's under the assumption that you've shown the entire XML in your question. If it's just part of a bigger XML file you need to show the whole thing.

---

Given that your XML is more like this:

```
<Root>
  <Data>
    <Object class="MA" Name="Sample">
      <bist name="act">false</bist>
      <bist name="Dynamic">1234</bist>
      <bist name="Fast">false</bist>
      <bist name="plane">false</bist>
      <bist name="Tnl">2232</bist>
    </Object>
  </Data>
</Root>
```

Then the code is probably going to be more like this:

```
private void mGetTnlFromXML(string oldTnl)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("sample.xml");
    foreach (var element in doc.Root.Element("Data").Elements("Object"))
    {
        var dynamic = element.Elements("bist").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "dynamic").First().Value;
        if (dynamic == oldTnl)
        {
            var tnl = element.Elements("bist").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Tnl").First().Value;
            MessageBox.Show(tnl);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems OK. I will try it. Thanks. The whole xml just consist of the same "Object" over and over.

Comment: i keep getting error that "sequence has no elements" on the "var dynamic...." and I think it will be the same with "var tnl...." inside the if statement.

Comment: @mygtwo - Yes, it's because the XML you posted wasn't your complete XML. You need to provide the correct XML to get the correct code.

Comment: Hi, you are right. Your code works. Thanks! My complete xml file is different tho, see the edit I made above... This is the reason why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @mygtwo - I've updated your question to show the XML in the right place. You shouldn't change the question to invalidate existing answers, so what I've done is added the XML at the bottom.

Comment: :).. it was working nicely until I added namespace on the root then it does not work again. how to deal with this? basically, from <Root> to <Root xmlns="http:something">

Comment: @mygtwo - That's what namespaces do. Can you add the new XML to the end of your question?

Comment: Thanks again. Finally, working again. I added namespace in all the query such as (ns + "Data") and so on... after declaring ns with XNamespace.

Comment: @mygtwo - That's the way to do it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Xml the Enigmativity provided, we can reduce this to a line of XPath:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(@"
<Root>
  <Object class=""MA"" Name=""Sample"">
    <bist name = ""act"" > false </bist >
    <bist name = ""Dynamic"" > 1234 </bist >
    <bist name = ""Fast"" > false </bist >
    <bist name = ""plane"" > false </bist >
    <bist name = ""Tnl"" > 2232 </bist >
  </Object >
  <Object class= ""MA"" Name = ""Sample"" >
      <bist name = ""act"" > false </bist >
      <bist name = ""Dynamic"" > 1234 </bist >
      <bist name = ""Fast"" > false </bist >
      <bist name = ""plane"" > false </bist >
      <bist name = ""Tnl"" > 2232 </bist >
  </Object >
</Root >");

xml.XPathSelectElements("//Object[bist[@name='Dynamic']]/bist[@name='Tnl']").Dump();
```

That translates to:

- `//Object[...]` - find the "Object" which has....
- `bist[@name='Dynamic']` - a "bist" element with attrib "name" equal to "Dynamic"
- `/bist[...]` - then take the "bist" element under that "Object" which has...
- `@name='Tnl'` - attribute "name" equals to "tnl"

Comment: Thank you... I will try it. :)

Comment: hi, this works but its not the solution to this particular problem. thanks a lot again, i also learned from your contribution... :)